# Quartz multitenancy with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I just need to create a cron schedular for my application to perform some db manipulation in a specific day of year. Since there are multiple clients in the application we are managing the multitenant approach and each client having a separate database.

once the schedular is triggered just need to update all the databases and this need to be handle from the quartz schedular.

I need your help to handle this scenario since i am new to java development.

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {
    @Autowired
    final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public QuartzConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    SpringBeanJobFactory createSpringBeanJobFactory() {
        return new SpringBeanJobFactory() {
            @Override
            protected Object createJobInstance
                    (final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
                final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
                applicationContext
                        .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                        .autowireBean(job);
                return job;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean createSchedulerFactory
            (SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory, Trigger trigger) {

        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory
                = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactory.setAutoStartup(true);
        schedulerFactory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        schedulerFactory.setTriggers(trigger);
        springBeanJobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory);
        return schedulerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(JobDetail jobDetail) {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 * * * ?");
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setName("leave-entitlement-carry-forward-trigger");
        return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobClass(Scheduler.class);
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setName("leave-entitlement-carry-forward");
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return jobDetailFactoryBean;
    }
}
```